# C# WindowsForms/UserControl: Unable to find assembly when trying to switch to designer view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, user-controls, designer

A complex UserControl of mine includes a number of standard controls (Buttons, TextBoxes, etc.), and a few simpler user controls of my own.
When I am trying to view the control in designer view, Visual Studio 2013 Pro tells me:

> "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: ", 
>   "Unable to find assembly 'Dktech.Infrastructure, Version=2016.4.26.702, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. "

All of the user controls nested in the control under question can be viewed in designer view. I also could call the designer view for the control until recently, but all of a sudden the error messages came, and I don't have an idea how to search for the possible reason. **What is the experience** and the **best practices** how to cope with this malady?

The **call stack** dump (below) does not tell anything comprehensible to me:

> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
>   at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
>   at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
>   at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader reader, Boolean isMetaData)
>   at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error.  When you use version numbers like 2016.4.26.702 then that gets to be a rather common mishap.  It was not intended to store dates.  Review your build procedure, always favor [AssemblyFileVersion] instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I did the following: replaced the version infos in the assembly containing the control and of the assembly which it tries to load with
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")] 
and rebuilt the assembly. Nothing has changed. 
I closed the solution, loaded it again and rebuilt the solution 
It still looks for Version=2016.4.26.702, and I do not find where in the project this information is stored. Ctrl+F on "2016.4.26.702" brings no result.

Concerning versioning: I am using auto version increment, and I never had such a problem.

Comment: Hans, I deleted manually the .suo file and all the object folders, and rebuilt. No effect: it is still after "2016.4.26.702". I search through the whole solution folder (\*.*), but "2016.4.26.702" could not be found anywhere.
Do you have a tip how to get rid of it / come back to the "simple" way of versioning? Does anybody know? TIA; Alex.

Comment: I very much doubt I can find it for you.  The most typical almost-impossible-to-find location is a form's .resx file.  It can contain an object that was serialized with BinaryFormatter and converted to a string with Convert.ToBase64String().  So you can no longer see the version number.

Comment: The next thing I am going to try is to use brute force as follows: I will define a new UserControl and copy all elements of the old one in there. I will report if it succeeds.

Comment: After an hour or so of experiments (under Hans' wise guidance and inspiration) I succeeded in getting my designer view back. What I did is literally as follows: 
(1)  in MyControl.designer.cs InitializeControls() commented out the reference to "resources"
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(...);
and all other mentions of "Resources"
 ... to be continued in the next comment ...

Comment: (2) opened the MyControl.rex with a text editor and commented out all entries like 
 <data name="m_ilLightboxIcons.ImageStream" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
<value>AAEAAAD...</value></data>
(3) made a few cosmetic changes to make the class to compile (references to an ImageList in my case)

Now the class compiled and was visible in designer view. All I needed to do was to re-connect the image list. But I still do not believe that the cause was the [AssemblyVersion] : I have been using the BuildVersionIncrement Add-On since many years, without any problems.

Comment: I remarked a pattern in the behavior of the control. The user control under question (called MyControl in the above postings) contains another UserControl, e.g. MyInnerControl. The latter has a get/set that connects an instance of MyInnerControlValue with the state of the element controls of MyInnerControl.

When trying to build up designer view, MS VS 2013 always creates an instance of MyInnerControlValue and adds it to the resources of MyControl. If I manually delete it in the resources, the designer view is built up correctly, otherwise I still get that 'Unable to find assembly' error.